# Site root for backend and frontend

Tags: php

Let's say that I have this website file root structure:

- frontend /home/username/public_html/
- backend /home/username/public_html/admin/

In frontend folder there is a file called config.php. In this file I get the site root of my website like this:

```
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
```

This file is also included in both index files (index.php) in frontend and backend. But for backend, the root is /home/username/public_html/admin/, which should actually be /home/username/public_html/. How can I do this, in one line, in config.php?

**LE:**

Demo code http://pastebin.com/LGrrJzaV

Comment: why would you want this in one line? Just define a FRONTROOT and a BACKROOT, and link to those places. You need this too if you want to link from your front-end to your backend ("login button") etc.

Comment: Even if I setup a FRONTROOT and a BACKROOT, I want to use ONLY one config.php file in my project, located (usually) in frontend.

Comment: So? That one file has frontroot and backroot. And if you link to a frontend-page you prepend "frontroot", and if you need to link to a backend page, you use "backroot".

Comment: I don't think I've explained this correctly. Check this out http://pastebin.com/LGrrJzaV

Comment: I have no clue what the problem is. Don't use the dirname thingy at all? Just define your roots as they are. If you are looking for a file in the frontend (even if you are in the backend), use frontroot. If you are looking for a file in the structrue of the backroot, use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**FILE**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) gives you the full path and filename of the file.

The [dirname()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) returns the path of the parent directory.

**So, if you use:**

```
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
```

It gives you the directory structure for the location of the current script.

**To be inside the `admin/` and have returned the previous folder:**

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__);

define("ROOT", $path.'/../');

// Outputs:  /home/username/public_html/
```

**In one line being inside `admin/`:**

```
define("ROOT", dirname(__FILE__).'/../');
```

---

## EDITED

Have the same path for both locations in one line:

```
define("ROOT", (strpos(dirname(__FILE__), "admin")>=0) ? (str_replace("admin", "", dirname(__FILE__))) : (dirname(__FILE__)));
```

**This will output on both index.php:**

- **frontend** /home/username/public_html/       -> `/home/username/public_html`
- **backend** /home/username/public_html/admin/  -> `/home/username/public_html`

Comment: This I understand. But how do you get ONLY the frontend path when you are in either frontend or backend?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
define('ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

Comment: This will not return the file root (like /home/username/public_html/).

Comment: You're right! Guess I've been working a bit too much in an environment where this is in fact the right way of doing it - my bad.