# How to include file relative to current file instead of parent file?

Tags: php, variables

I know this subject has been discussed in SO but yet I wasn't able to find a solution.

I have assign.php:

```
$a=1;
```

require.php:

```
require "assign.php";
```

and echo.php:

```
require "require.php"
echo $a;
```

which outputs 1.
problem is, when I want to use "require.php" from a different location, without having duplicate files. for example,

/folder/echo.php:

```
require "../require.php";
echo $a;
```

won't work, since require.php is trying to require /folder/assign.php which doesn't exist.

Trying to use a full url in require.php:

```
require "http://site.com/assign.php";
```

won't work either because the code isn't being included, but compiled, and since $a is not global, it is undefiend.

I was told by some that using globals is really not recommended.

Also using a filesystem full path is said to be dangerous.

What is the solution? How can I make sure require.php will always go for the right path for assign.php, no matter where require.php is included from?

Comment: What does this have to do with escaping?  You are talking about file paths.  Also where did you hear that full filepaths are dangerous?  You would not want to print them as output for all to see, but they are fine in code.

Comment: What _is_ the path of the file you are trying to access from another location?  If they're on the same filesystem, you certainly _can_ get the paths right, even if it takes multiple `../../`

Comment: That question had absolutely nothing to do with the title.  Renamed.

Comment: Reading your paths over again, looks like `require.php` is at the root and you want it in `folder/echo.php`.  So you need `require '../../require.php'`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682268/site-root-for-backend-and-frontend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a global constant and use that.

```
define('ROOT_PATH', rtrim(dirname(__FILE__), "\\/"));

require ROOT_PATH . '/file.php';
```

Comment: should I include the first line in every page or is it valid for the whole session?

Answer (score 5):

in `require.php` you should use

```
require dirname(__FILE__). "/assign.php";
```

This will include correct file by giving the full path, generated on the fly.